# Any ideas how to stop the Windows version QGIS crashing on exit?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, installation

I’m hoping someone can help.  I know that there’s been a bug with QGIS crashing on exit, but I was hoping that this has been resolved with the latest release of the software (the 64bit version for Windows).  I’ve installed 3.8.0 'Zanzibar' and the LTR 3.4.9 'Madeira', but no such luck with either of these – QGIS continues to crash on exit. I’ve even installed the software using OSGeo4W (64bit), though exactly the same thing happens.

I’ve read somewhere that the best way to come over this issue is to uninstall the version that’s crashing and then to conduct a reinstall.  I thought I had been doing this, but I guess some bogus code is being left on the PC, which could be the culprit...

So, here’s the question: when I’ve done an uninstall do I then need to go into regedit and remove every single occurrence of QGIS and similarly remove the entire contents of the ‘.qgis2’ folder, comprising the cache and python settings etc?

Should any other QGIS folders be removed?

Do I need to completely remove all mention of QGIS from the PC?

Is there anything that can potentially safely stay?

Ultimately, I just want to overcome this issue and I wanted to hear from others on this forum before reporting this.

Comment: Widely reported bug ??

Comment: Do you mean this issue https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29656? Have you tried to make a new profile as suggested?